# Browser Mode / emulation setting for Firefox

Tags: firefox, emulation

so on Internet Explorer if you load up the developer tools (F12) you have a nice drop down menu that lets you select the Browser Mode, IE 7, 8, 9 etc. Is there an option for this on Firefox? I've searched all over google etc and can't find anything like it. Really surprised if Microsoft have got one over on Firefox!

I have firebug installed too but I didn't see anything in there about it either.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't anything like that in Firefox.

What's in IE is not really quite emulation; Microsoft actually ships multiple versions of the rendering engine and websites can request a specific one to be rendered with.  At that point, letting the user select one is just a matter of adding a user interface for it.

But Firefox has the minor constraints of limited (compared to Microsoft) manpower and needing to have a finite download size (not an issue for IE, of course).  So it can't exactly be shipping (and maintaining with security fixes!) multiple incompatible versions of the rendering engine.

As Amar said, the right approach for Firefox is to just install multiple versions side by side (something that's quite difficult with IE).